Error building URL for Flask endpoint using Flask-Marshmallow
I'm developing a RESTful API with Flask and encountering an issue when trying to build URLs for my endpoints using Flask-Marshmallow. Whenever I access a route that uses ma.URLFor in my Marshmallow schema, I encounter the following error:
werkzeug.routing.exceptions.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'cursodetail'. Did you forget to specify values ['id']?

Here's how I'm setting up the CursoSchema schema:
from api import ma
from ..models import curso_model
from marshmallow import fields

class CursoSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = curso_model.Curso
        load_instance = True
        fields = ("id", "nome", "descricao", "_links")

    nome = fields.String(required=True)
    descricao = fields.String(required=True)

    _links = ma.Hyperlinks(
        {
            "get": ma.URLFor("cursodetail", id="<id>"),
            "put": ma.URLFor("cursodetail", id="<id>"),
            "delete": ma.URLFor("cursodetail", id="<id>")
        }
    )

My routes are defined in curso_views.py as follows:
from flask import Blueprint, jsonify, request
from flask.views import MethodView
from api import db, ma
from ..models import curso_model
from ..schemas import curso_schema

curso_bp = Blueprint('curso', __name__)

class CursoListView(MethodView):
    def get(self):
        cursos = curso_model.Curso.query.all()
        return jsonify(curso_schema.CursoSchema(many=True).dump(cursos))

curso_bp.add_url_rule('/cursos', view_func=CursoListView.as_view('curso_list'))

# Endpoint for course details
@curso_bp.route('/cursos/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def cursodetail(id):
    curso = curso_model.Curso.query.get_or_404(id)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return jsonify(curso_schema.CursoSchema().dump(curso))
    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        # Logic to update the course
        return jsonify(message='Course updated successfully')
    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        # Logic to delete the course
        return jsonify(message='Course deleted successfully')

my terminal error:
C:\Users\ferre\PycharmProjects\FlaskAPIflask\.venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\ferre\PycharmProjects\FlaskAPIflask\api\run.py 
 * Serving Flask app 'api'
 * Debug mode: on
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 108-576-652
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Jul/2024 20:38:58] "GET /cursos HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ferre\PycharmProjects\FlaskAPIflask\.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1498, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ferre\PycharmProjects\FlaskAPIflask\.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1476, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ferre\PycharmProjects\FlaskAPIflask\.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 298, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ferre\PycharmProjects\FlaskAPIflask\.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 295, in error_router
    return self.handle_error(e)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ferre\PycharmProjects\FlaskAPIflask\.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 310, in handle_error
    _handle_flask_propagate_exceptions_config(current_app, e)
  File "C:\Users\ferre\PycharmProjects\FlaskAPIflask\.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1473, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ferre\PycharmProjects\FlaskAPIflask\.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 882, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ferre\PycharmProjects\FlaskAPIflask\.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 298, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ferre\PycharmProjects\FlaskAPIflask\.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 295, in error_router
    return self.handle_error(e)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ferre\PycharmProjects\FlaskAPIflask\.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 310, in handle_error
    _handle_flask_propagate_exceptions_config(current_app, e)
  File "C:\Users\ferre\PycharmProjects\FlaskAPIflask\.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 880, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ferre\PycharmProjects\FlaskAPIflask\.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 865, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ferre\PycharmProjects\FlaskAPIflask\.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 489, in wrapper
    resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ferre\PycharmProjects\FlaskAPIflask\.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\views.py", line 110, in view
    return current_app.ensure_sync(self.dispatch_request)(**kwargs)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ferre\PycharmProjects\FlaskAPIflask\.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 604, in dispatch_request
    resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ferre\PycharmProjects\FlaskAPIflask\api\views\curso_views.py", line 13, in get
    return paginate(Curso,cs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ferre\PycharmProjects\FlaskAPIflask\api\paginate.py", line 24, in paginate
    'results':schema.dump(page_obj.items)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ferre\PycharmProjects\FlaskAPIflask\.venv\Lib\site-packages\marshmallow\schema.py", line 549, in dump
    result = self._serialize(processed_obj, many=many)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ferre\PycharmProjects\FlaskAPIflask\.venv\Lib\site-packages\marshmallow\schema.py", line 512, in _serialize
    self._serialize(d, many=False)
  File "C:\Users\ferre\PycharmProjects\FlaskAPIflask\.venv\Lib\site-packages\marshmallow\schema.py", line 517, in _serialize
    value = field_obj.serialize(attr_name, obj, accessor=self.get_attribute)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ferre\PycharmProjects\FlaskAPIflask\.venv\Lib\site-packages\marshmallow\fields.py", line 341, in serialize
    return self._serialize(value, attr, obj, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ferre\PycharmProjects\FlaskAPIflask\.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_marshmallow\fields.py", line 209, in _serialize
    return _rapply(self.schema, _url_val, key=attr, obj=obj)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ferre\PycharmProjects\FlaskAPIflask\.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_marshmallow\fields.py", line 158, in _rapply
    return {key: _rapply(value, func, *args, **kwargs) for key, value in d.items()}
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ferre\PycharmProjects\FlaskAPIflask\.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_marshmallow\fields.py", line 160, in _rapply
    return func(d, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ferre\PycharmProjects\FlaskAPIflask\.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_marshmallow\fields.py", line 168, in _url_val
    return val.serialize(key, obj, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ferre\PycharmProjects\FlaskAPIflask\.venv\Lib\site-packages\marshmallow\fields.py", line 341, in serialize
    return self._serialize(value, attr, obj, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ferre\PycharmProjects\FlaskAPIflask\.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_marshmallow\fields.py", line 124, in _serialize
    return url_for(self.endpoint, **param_values)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ferre\PycharmProjects\FlaskAPIflask\.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\helpers.py", line 220, in url_for
    return current_app.url_for(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ferre\PycharmProjects\FlaskAPIflask\.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1084, in url_for
    return self.handle_url_build_error(error, endpoint, values)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ferre\PycharmProjects\FlaskAPIflask\.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1073, in url_for
    rv = url_adapter.build(  # type: ignore[union-attr]
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ferre\PycharmProjects\FlaskAPIflask\.venv\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\routing\map.py", line 924, in build
    raise BuildError(endpoint, values, method, self)
werkzeug.routing.exceptions.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'cursodetail'. Did you forget to specify values ['id']?

myterminalpycharm
I've verified that the HTTP methods (GET, PUT, DELETE) are correct and that the cursodetail endpoint is defined with an id parameter. However, I continue to receive the aforementioned error when trying to access the route. How can I resolve this issue?
